# Why do all bootstrap panels collapse at once when using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

1. Why my panel collapse all in 1st click.
2. I just want to open one panel at a time.
3. Why the image is flickering when i click the link
4. not working in firefox

here is the part of the code [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Bv9MlBbZCu)

see my work here ..[link](http://test.joeyyap.com/book/book.asp)

Below is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.BOOKMore', function(e) {
event.preventDefault();

$('#myAccordion').find('#collapsible-1, #collapsible-2, #collapsible-3').collapse('hide');
$('#myBeginner').find('#beginner-1, #beginner-2, #beginner-3, #beginner-4,  #beginner-5, #beginner-6').collapse('hide');
$('#myAdvanced').find('#advanced-1, #advanced-2, #advanced-3, #advanced-4, #advanced-5, #advanced-6').collapse('hide');
$('#myAdvanced01').find('#advanced-7, #advanced-8, #advanced-9').collapse('hide');
$('#categoryMyStarter').find('#reference-1, #reference-2, #reference-3, #reference-4,  #reference-5, #reference-6').collapse('hide');

e.stopPropagation();

$(this).parent().next().collapse('show');

});
```

Comment: For this case and future referance, pls always include key sections of source code in post to help users assess the problem and whether they can help - relying solely on external fiddle or simliar is bad form (see 'Help others reproduce issue' in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please put your code on fiddle